# Audiorecorder, Choosing the input channels. Mac and RME

Tags: macos, matlab, audiorecord

I am trying to simply record sound through an external sound card: RME Fireface 400.

This is the code I am using:

```
AO = audioplayer(mls_o,fs,16,5); % mls_o is the signal that is played.
AI = audiorecorder(fs,16,2,5);   % 2 CHANNELS BUT HOW DO I ASSIGN THEM
play(AO);%playing
recordblocking(AI,1,2);%recording
y_rec=getaudiodata(AI);
delete(AI);% Deleting the objects
delete(AO);
```

I can only chose the number of channels, but not to address them.

Audiorecorder only supports 2 channels and Fireface have 8 input channels. I have to use the first two analog: ch5 and ch6. However, by default audio recorder only look 1st and 2nd one, which are mic inputs.

Otherwise do you know any other way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with just the `audiorecorder` object. Check out the [`playrec` library](http://www.playrec.co.uk/) and [`pa-wavplay` FileExchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4017), either of which should be capable of doing what you need. I believe [Psychtoolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/HomePage) also allows you to do this, but that might be overkill for your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot wakjah. I have tried playrec libraries but those are asio for windows, not for mac. I should then compile the files but I have no idea about how to do that.

I will check Psychtoolbox and see how that works, but still I am impressed about the fact that there is no easy solution for such a simple task. Thanks for the help

Comment: According to the front page, Playrec uses PortAudio, which will work on Mac. It also comes with a few compilation scripts, which look fairly easy to use. The only difficult bit to compile might be PortAudio (IIRC it doesn't come with binaries, but I might be wrong here). I agree that this seems like it should be a simple thing to do with the `audiorecorder` object, and it's a bit strange that it's overlooked...